# CORS is not working in web api with OWIN authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cors, owin, katana

In my application i am using  web api with token based authentication with CORS support, but when client request for the token, an error occured due to CORS (Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at (my site name) . This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.)

I had configured everything required for CORS support ( i think so). here my configuration

Owin start up class

```
   public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {


            var config = new HttpConfiguration
            {
                DependencyResolver = new StructureMapWebApiDependencyResolver(container)

            };


            WebApiConfig.Register(config);  // registering web api configuration
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);  // cors for owin token pipeline
            app.UseWebApi(config);
            ConfigureOAuth(app);


        }

        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var oAuthAuthorizationServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {

                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
            };
            // Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthAuthorizationServerOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

        }
    }
```

And my  webapi configuration

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.EnableCors();  // Corse support for Web api
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); // attribute based urls

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
    }
```

here configuration in web.config

```
<system.webserver>
 <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <!-- Adding the following custom HttpHeader will help prevent CORS from stopping the Request-->
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webserver>
```

and my request header from mozilla

```
Accept  application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Length  67
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host    talenterp
Origin  http://192.168.1.11:85
Referer http://192.168.1.11:85/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
```

The URLs of Apps are

Server app (which should support CORS)

```
{http://talenterp}
```

Token end point :

```
{http://talenterp/token}
```

Client app

```
{http://talentmvc:85}
```

NB: I already added

```
context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
```

in GrantResourceOwnerCredentials() method of my AuthorizationServerProvider

Comment: resolved.. the problem was over configuration CORS   app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll); config.EnableCors();  context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });   i just removed   first one

Comment: It is probably better to remove the config.EnableCors() line rather than the app.UserCors(). The former doesn't use OWIN, the latter does. Moving forward it's better to use OWIN pipeline setups.

Comment: @BinsonEldhose please accept an anwer.

Comment: You also need to remove <customHeaders> from web.config, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33664502/631527

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Be sure you've got only

> app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

configured, and **not** also the old style 'config.EnableCors()' in your Global.asax or WebApiConfig. Furthermore: **place the above statement as the first one in your owin Startup class**. Yes that really makes a difference, setting it later can also cause cors to not work.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        ... etc
```

Comment: How can we customize the CORS in OWIN? like for example, I want to allow only this url: http://myapp.com

Comment: @fiberOptics create a CorsPolicy for that and add the origins you want, create a policyProvider and add that to a CorsOptions object

Comment: This article describes how to provide a custom CORS policy: http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-webapi-cors

Comment: This should be marked as a correct answer nowadays. Thank you!

Comment: Moved the UseCors call to the first in the Configuration method, and it solved our 405 issue.  Postman worked fine, but it was 405ing from Chrome.

Comment: Moving the line up to the top of the Configuration method fixed mine too.  Thanks!

Comment: `place the above statement as the first one in your owin Startup class.` .... 2 hours of my life wasted...

Comment: @Pogrindis *only* two hours? I remember when first dealing with WebApi wasting much longer on what turned out to be just a middleware registration order issue.

Comment: @Ted I bet you wont waste even 10 mins when you come across it again ;) - Don't worry though, I've had the embarrassment of googling things, finding results of SO and realizing I posted the answer.. We're all allowed our senior moments!

Comment: And again, and again @Pogrindis. Some kind of "stackenfreude" where you delight in your own misfortune as it leads you back to your own stackoverflow answer that you'd completely forgotten about. It's astonishing how often that happens.

Comment: This worked for me, along with doing this... 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41988719/3284707

Answer (score 10):

OWIN and Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors are two separate libraries and each one needs separate configuration.

Disable use of CORS with OWIN:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
        //app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

Find GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method and add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to context so when it returns a call after authentication is completed that browser finds the header and accepts it.

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "http://localhost" });
```

Now install Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors package from Nuget to your webapi project, and add this to Register method

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost, ", "accept,accesstoken,authorization,cache-control,pragma,content-type,origin", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,TRACE,HEAD,OPTIONS");

        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

This did it for me.

Comment: actually this worked for me, for upper version on owin this worked out. +1

Comment: I know it have passed nearly 6 months since you posted this answer but maybe you still remember this. I am interested in, why did you write "http: //localhost, " in var cors=new EnableCorsAttribute("http: //localhost, "...  and just not var cors=new EnableCorsAttribute("http: //localhost"... ? I mean I am confused with ", "(comma and space) after "http: //localhost

Comment: @Dato that's definitely a leftover from the list of domains that I had in my code. The EnableCorsAttribute allows you pass a list of domains in one string. Here is a reference [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.cors.enablecorsattribute.enablecorsattribute)

Comment: @DadoKljuco Thanks for your response. Funny thing is that var cors=new EnableCorsAttribute("http: //localhost, "... works nice but var cors=new EnableCorsAttribute("http: //localhost"... fails. And this was the reason why I was confused

Answer (score 3):

Especially if you are having problem with the Web API bearer token when using CORS then dont forget to put "TOKEN" in the list of your allowed methods.

Please put the code in your system.webServer of web.config, that is how i solved mine

```
<customHeaders>
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, TOKEN" />
 </customHeaders>
```

Comment: adding TOKEN to values fixed my problem while all other solutions was not working!

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. In addition to the above indications (using app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll) only, and setting it up as first thing), I had to specify the following in the application Web.config file to be able to handle Option Requests:

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>          
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Due to some headers that I was sending in the authentication request, an Options request is sent before the actual POST request, and it needs to return the correct 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header before the POST is sent.

If none of the CORS headers are returned by the options response, then the POST will not be sent at all. The added configuration enables this behaviour as well as for Trace.

As explained in this [post](https://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-webapi-cors)

Comment: For me, I had to ensure that I removed the OPTIONSVerbHandler, otherwise the OWIN Cors solution didn't do anything (code ran, but nothing happened from it).

Answer (score 1):

I had this similar problem, I tried all the options above in startup.cs i added app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll); at the top and in the WebApiConfig i disabled

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    //var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
    //config.EnableCors(cors);
}
```

and also disabled cors in

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
}
```

And repeated this in reverse order and also included entries in `web.config` but all did not work.

When I begun asking myself why is `app.UseWebApi(config);` not accessible yet I have seen it work somewhere. I looked around and found out installing `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost` fixes it.

Eventually, it fixed the whole problem, though `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll)` has to be placed first in the startup.cs method.  In fact without `app.UseWebApi(config)`, I tested in postman and the end points actually didn't exist. Overall it's working pretty well for me now.