# The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

I'm using Angular and ASP.NET API. The issue I'm facing: when I add CORS in the API code, it works on Internet Explorer but does not work on Chrome and Firefox.

Here is the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:41028/api/values/abc. The
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *',
>   but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:44796' is therefore
>   not allowed access.

This is the code I added in the `web.config` file:

```
<system.webServer>
...
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
      <!-- Adding the following custom HttpHeader will help prevent CORS errors -->
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
...
</system.webServer>
```

In the `WebApiConfigFile.cs` file I added:

```
var CorsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute("* ","* ", "* ");
        config.EnableCors(CorsAttribute);
```

I'm using CORS for the first time. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Either add headers statically in the web.config or dynamically with the cors attribute. Not both.

Comment: sorry, can you explain as i said i am new.... with example? i am even new asking questions on stack overflow

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You are setting CORS twice. I think that is the issue.

Please remove any one CORS settings. You can either remove it from `web.config` or from `WebApiConfigFile.cs`.

Answer (score 4):

Chrome and Firefox use what is called a pre-flight check using the "OPTIONS" verb.

So, you have to add "OPTIONS" to the allowed methods in the web.config.  You also may have to add some code to the Application_Begin request, like this answer suggests:
[Handling CORS Preflight requests to ASP.NET MVC actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624386/handling-cors-preflight-requests-to-asp-net-mvc-actions)

Here are some resources for CORS:

[IIS hijacks CORS Preflight OPTIONS request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495240/iis-hijacks-cors-preflight-options-request)

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Answer (score 2):

All other solutions provided for webAPI. This solution is for when you using webservice(.asmx) as API

Remove 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' details from either in `Global.asax.cs` file's `begin_request` function or in `web.config`. Because this setting must be in one place only

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue because I put the `app.UseCors` after `ConfigureOAuth`.  Change the order fix the problem.

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        ConfigureOAuth(app);

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);

        // Used to put this line after ConfigureAuth(app), 
        // app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

Here is the detail in my case:

- At the beginning I got Origin is not allowed in 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', when calling `\token`.
- LSo I add the customHeader including 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'Access-Control-Allow-headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-methods'.  It fixed the `\token` request.
- But then I got duplicate 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' when calling detail api.  There are a lot suggestions, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343384/the-access-control-allow-origin-header-contains-multiple-values) just couldn't fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After I put the exact domain instead of * (see below), it worked for me.

var CorsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute("https://www.mywebsite.com","*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(CorsAttribute);

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error and the reason was that

> "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"

header was already present in the IIS *HTTP Response Headers* list.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCcOG.png)

Removing it from the list worked for me.