# Prevent token based authorization of preflight OPTIONS requests in asp.net 5 (vNext)

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, cors, asp.net-core, jwt

I have an almost working implementation of OAuth2 in asp.net 5 (RC1). My solution is based upon the code given by Mark Hughes in [Token Based Authentication in ASP.NET 5 (vNext)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29048122/token-based-authentication-in-asp-net-5-vnext), which is brilliant.

My problem is that my setup is using CORS requests and almost every request is preceded by an OPTIONS request. Even though I only apply the Authorize attribute to the GetAll controller action/method, as shown below, the preceding OPTIONS request is authorized as well.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TextController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize("Bearer", Roles = "admin")]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetAll()
    {
        return _repository.GetAll;
    }

    ...
}
```

The authorization service setup in startup.cs looks like this:

```
services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
        {
            auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme‌​)
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
        });
```

Is ther any way I can change the behavior of the authorization middleware to skip authorization of OPTIONS requests?

Note:

I have tried creating my own authorization attribute, but for some reason IsAuthenticated always evaluates to false, as if the authorization has not happened yet when reaching this code:

```
public class BearerAuthorizationAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly string Role;
    public BearerAuthorizationAttribute(string Role = null)
    {
        this.Role = Role;
    }
    [Authorize("Bearer")]
    public void OnAuthorization(Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        string meth = context.HttpContext.Request.Method;
        if (meth != "OPTIONS")
        {

            if (!context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                context.Result = new ContentResult() { Content = "Unauthorized", StatusCode = 401 };
                return;
            }
            if (Role != null && !context.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(Role))
            {
                context.Result = new ContentResult() { Content = "Unauthorized, role level insufficient", StatusCode = 401 };
                return;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out how to fix my problem. In my Startup.cs I was using `services.AddCors`, like so:

```
// Create CORS policies
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    // Define one or more CORS policies
    options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins(Configuration.Get<string[]>("AppSettings:AllowedOrigins")) // TODO: revisit and check if this can be more strict and still allow preflight OPTION requests
                        .AllowAnyMethod() 
                        .AllowAnyHeader();
        }
    );
});
// Apply CORS policy globally
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowSpecificOrigin"));
});
```

It turns out that this only worked partially.

**The solution** for me was to do `app.UseCors` in stead, i.e., delete the code above and doing this:

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins(Configuration.Get<string[]>("AppSettings:AllowedOrigins")) // TODO: revisit and check if this can be more strict and still allow preflight OPTION requests
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader();
});
```

When using `app.UseCors` I get fully working CORS handling, which bounces the OPTIONS reqests before they are being authorized.

The solution is inspired by [CORS is not working in web api with OWIN authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989769/cors-is-not-working-in-web-api-with-owin-authentication).