# how to enable cors options in asp.net web apis.?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cross-domain

How do I enable the CORS option in `asp.net` WebApi? I installed the package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` from nuget for CORS support. However, I am getting an error stating that `IAppBuilder` does not contain definition for `app.useCors`?

Comment: can you share the code you have tried?

Comment: app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

Comment: Have you tried everything in this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079813/how-to-make-cors-authentication-in-webapi-2

Comment: yes but app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll); says IaapBuilder could not found definition for UseCors

Comment: Have you installed the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost` and `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` NuGet packages?

Comment: thank you, I installed Microsoft.Owin.Cors and now its working fine

Comment: Happy to help! I've added the above comment as an answer to help others find it in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you have installed the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost` and `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` NuGet packages.