# OWIN preflight requests are not processed

Tags: c#, .net, cors, owin

All preflight requests from browsers to my Self-Host OWIN WebAPI are not processed by Middleware. If I make OPTIONS request from Postman they are processed. Why is such a behaviour?

> Request
>   URL:http://localhost:9000/api/v1/conversations/create?connectionId=13509f44-eacb-4950-8cc8-71bd37098975
>
> Request Method:OPTIONS
>
> Status Code:401 Unauthorized Remote
>
> Address:[::1]:9000
>
> Accept:*/*
>
> Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
>
> Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
>
> Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
>
> Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
>
> Connection:keep-alive
>
> Host:localhost:9000
>
> Origin:http://localhost:8080
>
> Referer:http://localhost:8080/
>
> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36

Response Headers for Chrome:

> Content-Length:0
>
> Date:Wed, 08 Feb 2017 04:17:26 GMT
>
> Server:Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
>
> WWW-Authenticate:NTLM

Response headers for Postman:

> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials →true
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin →chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
>
> Allow →POST
>
> Content-Length →76
>
> Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
>
> Date →Wed, 08 Feb 2017 04:21:02 GMT
>
> Server →Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

I added fake middleware to my appbuilder:

```
public void BuildWebApi(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        appBuilder.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
        {
            await next();
        });
```

and put breakpoint to line "await next()". So breakpoint doesn't stop while browser makes preflight request and stops while postman OPTIONS response.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989769/cors-is-not-working-in-web-api-with-owin-authentication and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079813/how-to-make-cors-authentication-in-webapi-2 may be relevant. Also it would probably help if you also included the request headers in your question.

Comment: UseCors not working because it also in background adds middleware that are not invoked on preflight requests from Chrome. Of course I've added UserCors() and config.EnableCors() but it has no effect.

Comment: OK, so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079813/how-to-make-cors-authentication-in-webapi-2/25758949#25758949 does not help you?

Comment: No, I haven't any xml config because of Self-Host. I've added request headers to question.

Comment: Please read the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079813/how-to-make-cors-authentication-in-webapi-2/25758949#25758949. It doesn’t use any XML config. Instead it involves: (1) Installing the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` nuget package, the `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` nuget package, and then (2) adding
`config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"))` above the `WebApiConfig.Register(config)` line in the `Startup.cs` file, then (3) adding  `app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll)` to the `Startup.Auth.cs` file. No XML config.

Comment: That not works also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved this by

```
HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)appBuilder.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
listener.AuthenticationSchemeSelectorDelegate = request =>
{
   if (request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
   {
       return AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;
   }
};
```