# Web Api 2 works with postman but fails with Angular 2

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api2

Postman request:
[image]

Everything works great with postman. I posted Bearer token on server and got expected result.

Angular 2 request:

```
    //app component
    test(){
        return this.httpService.get('api/user/get', 'application/json')
          .subscribe(data=>{
              console.log({'loggedIn': true, 'messageText': 'test succeeded'});
            },
            error=>{
              console.log({'loggedIn': false, 'messageText': error});
            }
          );
      }

//http-service
get(url:string, contentType:string):Observable<any> {
    let baseUrl:string = "http://localhost:1382/";

    let headers = new Headers({
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    });

    //append content-type to headers
    headers.append('Content-type', contentType);

    //check if localStorage contains token. If yes, append authorization to headers
    let token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    if (token !== '[object Object]' && token !== null) {
      headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer' + ' ' + token);
    }

    let requestOptions = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    //send get request
    return this.http.get(baseUrl + url, requestOptions)
      .map((res:Response)=>res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

And it says error:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:1382/api/user/get 405 (Method Not Allowed)

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:1382/api/user/get. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

<Error>
<Message>Authorization has been denied for this request.</Message>
</Error>
```

I enabled CORS in Web Api 2 web.config like following:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Authorization, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems a bit obvious, but have you debugged/checked it's actually hitting that code (i.e the token is being appended) and the token is actually valid? the `if (token !== '[object O...` statement looks a bit suspect to me. You could also check the traffic in fiddler. Sometimes you're not sending what you think you're sending! :)... Sometimes a malformed request can give the sort of error you're seeing.

Comment: What if you try to *hard-code* all request info (URL, headers, etc.) temporarily, just to make sure it's not the logic inside your `get()` method that's faulty? In other words, enter all data as strings just like you did in Postman.

Comment: could you look at the actual network request and verify that you have all headers added like with postman?

Comment: In the `WebApiConfig.cs` or `Global.asax` add `app.UseCors()`. Might need the nuget `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`

Answer (score 13):

It works in postman because that is an extension, it just sends the request. 
On the other hand when sending from a browser, for security reasons, requests are sent differently. 
First the browser sends an `OPTIONS` request (so called preflight request) to `http://foo.com/bar`. This is to determine whether it is acceptable to send the request with these parameters.

 Your backend should handle the request, respond and set response headers like:

- `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`
- `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`
- `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`
- `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`
- etc

After that, based on the headers of the `OPTIONS` response, the browser will send the `GET` to `http://foo.com/bar` IF everything is allowed, like origin, method, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You actually do have a preflight request (failing with 405).

You can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) why, probably due to Content-Type or any other header (X-Requested-With ?).

If you want to keep this preflight you have to handle it in webapi and disable authorization or at least return 200 (you can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095777/how-to-support-http-options-verb-in-asp-net-mvc-webapi-application#21458845))

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for your answers and advices. I summed up all this information and in addition I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39397016/4559099
in `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` I added `context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "http://localhost:4200" });`

And in `WebApiConfig` I added `config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200, ", "*", "*"));` and everything works great.

Actually I didn't understand why comment's author wrote `config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200, ", "*", "*"));` instead of `config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200", "*", "*"));` But it works fine. It will be really helpful if someone explains this.